# Passing a Block option to Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have a helper for adding new Searchfields for Ransack:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, type)
    new_object = f.object.send "build_#{type}"
    id = "new_#{type}"
    fields = f.send("#{type}_fields", new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(type.to_s + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

which let's me :

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Condition", f, :condition %>
```

but i need

```
<%= link_to_add_fields f, :condition do %>
  Add Condition
<% end %>
```

Which in turn gives me this error:

```
ArgumentError
wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)
```

I'm completely clueless on how to achieve this. Any good Samaritan out there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you let your helper accept a block?

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, type, &block)
  new_object = f.object.send "build_#{type}"
  id = "new_#{type}"
  fields = f.send("#{type}_fields", new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(type.to_s + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")}) do
    yield if block_given?
  end
end
```

You are getting this error because your helper requires three arguments. Your code example is only passing in two arguments: `f` and `:condition`. You need to pass the three arguments specified in the helper: `name`, `f`, or the form object, and `type`.

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Hoo Haa!", f, :association do %>
  Whatever you put here will be yielded by the block.
<% end %>
```

If you don't want the `name` argument, and instead you only want the block, change your helper to reflect this:

```
def link_to_add_fields(f, type, &block)
  # ...
end
```

Then it would like this:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields f, :association do %>
  This gets yielded
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh i actually tried that, from another SO Answer. It gives me: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)

Comment: Read my update. You are passing the wrong number arguments. Look at the helper: it needs three arguments. You are passing it two, only.

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code, still the same. Could you post the link block in the view also? (<% ... %>). Maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: My code is not the problem. It's your code that tries to invoke `link_to_add_field` it needs **3** arguments. You are passing **2** arguments.

Comment: Your Edit clarified a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Np. If you don't need the name argument, check out the last update. You can also remove it.